# Lotus notes automation from browser

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

I have been trying to automate Lotus Notes mail fillup from a browser interface.

After refering to Richard Schwartz's answer, i came up with this piece of code using the `Lotus.NotesSession` class.

```
function SendScriptMail() {
            var mToMail = document.getElementById('txtMailId').value
            var mSub = document.getElementById('txtSubject').value
            var mMsg = document.getElementById('txtContent').value
            var Password = "yyy"
alert("1");
            var MailFileServer = "xxx.com"
            var MailFile = "C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\mail\user.nsf"
alert("2")
            var Session;
            var Maildb;
            var UI;
            var NewMail;
            var From = "user@xxx.com"
            try {
alert("3")
                // Create the Activex object for NotesSession
                Session = new ActiveXObject("Lotus.NotesSession");
alert("4")
                if (Session == null) {
                    throw ("NoSession");
                } else {
                    Session.Initialize(Password);
                    // Get mail database
                    Maildb = Session.GetDatabase(MailFileServer, MailFile);
alert("5")
                    if (Maildb == null) {
                        throw ("NoMaildb");
                    } else {
                        NewMail = MailDB.CreateDocument();
                        if (MailDoc == null) {
                            throw ('NoMailDoc');
                        } else {
                            // Populate the fields
                            NewMail.AppendItemValue("Form", "Memo")
                            NewMail.AppendItemValue("SendTo", mToMail)
                            NewMail.AppendItemValue("From", From)
                            NewMail.AppendItemValue("Subject", mSub)
                            NewMail.AppendItemValue("Body", mMsg)
                            NewMail.Save(True, False)
                            NewMail.Send(False)

                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                // feel free to improve error handling...
                alert('Error while sending mail');
            }
        }
```

But now, alerts 1,2,3 are being trigerrd, and then the counter moves to the catch block. The lotus notes session is not being started.

In a powershell script that I was previously looking at there was a code `regsvr32 "$NotesInstallDir\nlsxbe.dll" /s` that was used before the `Session = new ActiveXObject("Lotus.NotesSession");`. Is there something similar in javascript too, if so how do i invoke that dll.

I think I've realised where I am going wrong. According to me, upto `alert("5")` things are good. But since `Lotus.NotesSession` doesn't have a `CreateDocument()` method, it is throwing the error.   I am not sure how to create the document and populate the values though.

Comment: Some versions of the installer for Lotus Notes fail to properly register NLSXBE.DLL.  E.g., see this IBM Technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21112239  This would affect all Notes applications that run on the computer but outside of the Notes client environment. I don't know of any hacks that would allow you to run regsvr32.exe from JavaScript. It would be a huge, huge security hole if that were possible. This is simply something that has to be corrected in the installation before your JavaScript can run.

Comment: i found out that the activex controller is working only in internet explorer, so i dont need to import the dll file. However, after mounting the database i am not sure how to proceed. can you please guide me through the next set of steps.

Comment: You'll proceed in pretty much the same way that you have been so far (i.e., initialize the session: call getDatabase and createDocument, and appendItemValue, except for the Body.  For that, you will use something like rtBody = NewMail.CreateRichTextItem("Body"), and then you will use the methods of the NotesRichTextItem class (e.g. AppendText, AppendTable, AppendStyle... see the doc for more) to create your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've chosen to use the Notes.NotesUIWorkspace class, you are working with the Notes client front-end.  It's running, and your users see what's happening on the screen.  Are you aware that there's a set of back-end classes (rooted in `Lotus.NotesSession`) instead of `Notes.NotesSession` and `Notes.NotesUIWorkspace`) that work directly with Notes database data, without causing the Notes client to grab focus and display everything that you're doing?

Working with the front-end means that in some cases (depending on the version of Notes that you are working with) you're not going to be working directly with the field names that are standard in Notes messages as stored and as seen in the back-end. You're going to be working with names used as temporary inputs in the form that is used to view and edit the message.  You can see these names by using Domino Designer to view the Memo form.

Instead of using 'SendTo', try using:

`MailDoc.Fieldsettext('EnterSendTo', mToMail)`

Regarding the Body field, there's no temporary field involved, however you haven't really explained the difficulty you are having.  Do you not know how to display the interface that you want in the browser?  Do you not know how to combine different inputs into a single `FieldSetText` call?  Or are you just dissatisfied with the fact that `FieldSetText` can't do any fancy formatting?  In the latter case, to get more formatting capability you may want to switch to using the back-end classes, which give you access to the `NotesRichTextItem` class, which has more formatting capabilities.

Comment: Here's a link to the doc for NotesSession. The page will auto-frame itself and show you an index of all the classes. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html

Comment: For multiple recipients, set the SendTo item to an array of strings. I.e., pass an array to the AppendItemValue() method.

Comment: `var mToMail = new Array("xxx@abc.com","yyy@abc.com"); NewMail.AppendItemValue("SendTo",mToMail)` isn't working.

Comment: I don't know why that wouldn't work, as it is the correct strategy for AppendItemValue in other languages. Another possible way is to use var toItem = NewMail.GetItem("SendTo"); and then write a loop that calls toItem.AppendToTextList() for each of the addresses that you require.